# How to get exact ISymbol image size in pixels

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I found the next code to convert ISymbol into bitmap image,
but how to know the suitable image size? (suppose we have a ITextSymbol)

```
private static Image PointSymbolToImage(ISymbol symbol, Size imageSize)
{
    double x = imageSize.Width / 2;
    double y = (imageSize.Height - 1) / 2;

    IPoint point = new PointClass();
    point.PutCoords(x, y);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    symbol.SetupDC(g.GetHdc().ToInt32(), null);
    try { symbol.Draw(point); }
    catch { }
    symbol.ResetDC();

    g.Dispose();

    return (Image)bmp;
}
```

---

For more details:

I used QueryBoundary but the dimensions returned after transforming to screen coordinates were wrong.
Next is my code:

Here symbol is ITextSymbol and (x, y) are the lat, lon coordinates of the symbol.

```
IPolygon boundary = new PolygonClass();
boundary.SetEmpty();

IDisplay screenDisplay = axMapControl1.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay as IDisplay;
IDisplayTransformation displayTransformation = screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;
IPoint point = new PointClass();
point.PutCoords(x, y);

symbol.QueryBoundary(screenDisplay.hDC, displayTransformation, point, boundary);

IPoint mapPoint = new PointClass();

int minX, minY;
mapPoint.PutCoords(boundary.Envelope.XMin, boundary.Envelope.YMin);
displayTransformation.FromMapPoint(mapPoint, out minX, out minY);

int maxX, maxY;
mapPoint.PutCoords(boundary.Envelope.XMax, boundary.Envelope.YMax);
displayTransformation.FromMapPoint(mapPoint, out maxX, out maxY);
```

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful in my comments to this related question: [Create a summary table of the symbology of all datasets in multiple mxd's](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27807/create-a-summary-table-of-the-symbology-of-all-datasets-in-multiple-mxds)

Answer (score 2):

If you need a formula for converting between points and pixels try here: [Convert Pixels to Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139655/convert-pixels-to-points) - stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

Try using [ISymbol.QueryBoundary](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/QueryBoundary_Method/001w00000372000000/) to get a polygon, then transform the polygon's envelope (via the displaytransformation) back into pixels.

Comment: I've already tried it, but the returned dimensions were different from the suitable ones.

Comment: +1 I believe this is the best approach. I've successfully used these exact steps to get the image size realiably.

Comment: Would you please share the steps you've followed.
I added some details to my question about what I've tested.
could you please check it, maybe I made some mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

to solve problem when ISymbol is ITextSymbol,
i used this:

```
if (symbol is ITextSymbol)
{
    using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1)))
    {
        stdole.IFontDisp font = (symbol as ITextSymbol).Font;
        size = graphics.MeasureString((symbol as ITextSymbol).Text, new Font(font.Name, (float)font.Size, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point));

        size.Width = (size.Width / 72) * graphics.DpiX;
        size.Height = (size.Height / 72) * graphics.DpiY;
    }
}
```

( thanks blah238 )

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved the problem. the next code shows how:

```
SizeF getSymbolSize(ISymbol symbol)
{
    SizeF size;

    if (symbol is ITextSymbol)
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1)))
        {
            stdole.IFontDisp font = (symbol as ITextSymbol).Font;
            size = graphics.MeasureString((symbol as ITextSymbol).Text, new Font(font.Name, (float)font.Weight, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point));
        }
    }
    else if (symbol is IMarkerSymbol)
    {
        float s = (float)(symbol as IMarkerSymbol).Size;

        size = new SizeF(s, s);
    }
    else
    {
        size = new SizeF(150.0f, 150.0f);
    }

    return size;
}
```

Comment: This method does not solve the problem, it does not give the suitable image size.
I hope someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

For a picture marker, you can try this:

```
if (symbol is IPictureMarkerSymbol)
            {
                IPictureMarkerSymbol pMarker = symbol as IPictureMarkerSymbol;
                pic = pMarker.Picture;
                size = new Size(pic.Width, pic.Height);
            }
```

And for convert the marker to image:

```
Image img = AxHostConverter.PictureDispToImage(pic);
```

more information about AxHostConverter class can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2007/07/30/converting-between-ipicturedisp-and-system-drawing-image/).